# Custom validators in BaseSerializer

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I want to use custom validators in BaseSerializer.

**First attempt:**

*Custom validator*:

```
class UserIdExists:
def __init__(self):
    self.MESSAGE_INCORRECT_USER = 'No user with this id.'

def __call__(self, user_id):
    exists = User.objects.filter(id=user_id).exists()
    if not exists:
            message = self.MESSAGE_INCORRECT_USER
            raise serializers.ValidationError(message, code='invalid')
```

and *BaseSerializer*:

```
class QuestionBaseSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):

   def to_internal_value(self, data):
      user_id = data.get('user_id')

      user_validator = UserIdExists()
      user_validator(user_id=user_id)
```

In case of a validation error, I received a message:

```
'["No user with this id."]'
```

But I would like to receive such a message:

```
'{"user_id": "No user with this id."}'
```

**Second attempt:**
*Custom validator:*

```
class UserIdExists:
    def __init__(self):
        self.MESSAGE_INCORRECT_USER = 'No user with this id.'

    def __call__(self, user_id, field=None):
        exists = User.objects.filter(id=user_id).exists()
        if not exists:
            if field:
                message = {field: self.MESSAGE_INCORRECT_USER}
                raise serializers.ValidationError(message, code='invalid')

        else:
            if not field:
                message = self.MESSAGE_INCORRECT_USER
                raise serializers.ValidationError(message, code='invalid')
```

And *BaseSerializer*:

```
class QuestionBaseSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        user_id = data.get('user_id')

        user_validator = UserIdExists()
        user_validator(user_id=user_id, field='user_id')
```

I get the expected message:

```
'{"user_id": "No user with this id."}'
```

---

**Am I doing the right thing? Can it be done more correctly?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `to_internal_value`, you should better use the functionalities that are made for validation specifically, that way it would be easier to extend/maintain because all you have to focus on is the validation logic, and not how to produce the internal value. The convention for validating fields is either through:

- Serializer field attribute [validators](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#validators) (a list of validators to run for the field)
- Serializer method [validate_field_name()](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#field-level-validation)
- Serializer method `validate()`

Here to simplify the explanation, we will validate to only allow odd-numbered `user_id`.

```
class UserIdExists:
    def __init__(self):
        self.MESSAGE_INCORRECT_USER = 'No user with this id.'

    def __call__(self, user_id):
        if user_id % 2 == 0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("No user with this id.")
        return user_id


class QuestionBaseSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField(
        validators=[UserIdExists()]
    )


class MathQuestionSerializer(QuestionBaseSerializer):
    description = serializers.CharField()
```

```
>>> from my_app.serializers import MathQuestionSerializer
>>>
>>> serializer = MathQuestionSerializer(data={'user_id': 2, 'description': "What is an imaginary number?"})
>>> serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise ValidationError(self.errors)
rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError: {'user_id': [ErrorDetail(string='No user with this id.', code='invalid')]}
>>> 
>>> serializer = MathQuestionSerializer(data={'user_id': 3, 'description': "What is an imaginary number?"})
>>> serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
True
```

As you can see, inheriting from `QuestionBaseSerializer` worked because it correctly validated the `user_id` field automatically ensuring it isn't an even number.

You can customize the validation further by choosing the 2nd style via implementing `validate_field_name()`:

```
class QuestionBaseSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField()

    def validate_user_id(self, user_id: int) -> int:
        validator = UserIdExists()
        return validator(user_id)


class MathQuestionSerializer(QuestionBaseSerializer):
    description = serializers.CharField()

    def validate_user_id(self, user_id: int) -> int:
        # Let's call the usual validation of even-odd numbers
        user_id_validated = super().validate_user_id(user_id)

        # Now, let's add additional validation of small numbers
        if user_id_validated < 10:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("No user with this id.")
        return user_id_validated
```

```
>>> serializer = MathQuestionSerializer(data={'user_id': 2, 'description': "What is an imaginary number?"})
>>> serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise ValidationError(self.errors)
rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError: {'user_id': [ErrorDetail(string='No user with this id.', code='invalid')]}
>>> 
>>> serializer = MathQuestionSerializer(data={'user_id': 3, 'description': "What is an imaginary number?"})
>>> serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise ValidationError(self.errors)
rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError: {'user_id': [ErrorDetail(string='No user with this id.', code='invalid')]}
>>> 
>>> serializer = MathQuestionSerializer(data={'user_id': 14, 'description': "What is an imaginary number?"})
>>> serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise ValidationError(self.errors)
rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError: {'user_id': [ErrorDetail(string='No user with this id.', code='invalid')]}
>>> 
>>> serializer = MathQuestionSerializer(data={'user_id': 15, 'description': "What is an imaginary number?"})
>>> serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
True
```

As you can see, the validation correctly checked if it is an odd number (the base validation) and is greater than 10 (the subclass validation).